# Excel Improve Formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-365

Looking to improve the below formula, file size is large and performance slower because of this, due to it being used 37K times

`=IFERROR(IF($A162<>"",IF(LEN(Teams!$BHR157)>0,LET(pattern,INDEX(Shifts!$I$3:$NC$402,MATCH($A162,Shifts!$A$3:$A$402,0),MATCH(BK$5,Shifts!$I$2:$NC$2,0)),IF(BK$5="","NA",IF(BK$5<Teams!$C157,"NE",IF(AND(Teams!$D157>0,BK$5>Teams!$D157),"NE",IF(IFERROR(NOT(VLOOKUP(BK$5,L_HOLS_SHIFT,2,FALSE)=0),FALSE),"CH",IF(MID(pattern,11,1)=0,MID(pattern,5,1),IF(AND(MID(pattern,5,1)=MID(pattern,11,1),MID(pattern,5,1)>0,SUMPRODUCT(--(MID(pattern,7,3)={"HOL","FLD","LID","UNP","ABS","CBR","LIS","MAT"}))),IF(MID(pattern,11,1)="0","",MID(pattern,7,3)),MID(pattern,5,1)+IF(SUMPRODUCT(--(MID(pattern,7,3)={"SSI","OVT"})),MID(pattern,11,1),"0")+IF(AND(MID(pattern,5,1)="0",MID(pattern,7,3)="SDS"),MID(pattern,11,1),"0")-IF(AND(MID(pattern,5,1)>"0",MID(pattern,7,3)="SDS"),MID(pattern,11,1),"0")-IF(SUMPRODUCT(--(MID(pattern,7,3)={"HOL","FLD","LID","UNP","ABS","CBR","LIS","MAT","SSO"})),MID(pattern,11,1),"0")))))))),""),""),"")`

pattern =  ROT000XXX000 (where XXX=HOL or UNP etc)

the main part that needs looking at starts

`IF(MID(pattern,11,1)=0,MID(pattern,5,1),IF(AND(MID(pattern,5,1)=MID(pattern,11,1),MID(pattern,5,1)>0,SUMPRODUCT(--(MID(pattern,7,3)={"HOL","FLD","LID","UNP","ABS","CBR","LIS","MAT"}))),`

This part of the code i need it to do the following.

Every 3 cells is a shift, so cell a would get the first digit after ROT and the first after XXX the next shift would get the second and the last shift would get the last digit.

1. Check if XXX has a value, if not show value for ROT depending on shift (this is split into 3 shifts so each number after XXX or ROT is the shift)
2. If XXX = SDS then i need it to check ROT for a value greater than 0 and deduct that, if 0 then it needs to add the value on (so if ROT080SDS880 it would need to remove the 8 from second shift and add to the first.
3. if XXX= SSI or OVT then add the hours to ROT and show
4. if XXX = "HOL","FLD","LID","UNP","ABS","CBR","LIS","MAT","SSO" then deduct the hours
5. if ROT value is same as XXX and its a deduction show the 3 letter code unless its 0 or blank in which case show nothing.
6. if deducting less than the full amount just deduct them hours

So with a SDS using ROT080SDS880

The Rota would have been

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
|  | 8 |  |

This needs to change to

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 8 |  |  |

Hope i have explained this ok.

Thanks

Comment: I can look more at this later, but for now, you execute `MID(pattern...)` 19 times in each cell, that's 703,000 executions alone.  If you wrapped the whole formula in a `LET()` statement you could re-use your MID results without recalculating them, a 6-fold improvement.  In the outer LET you'd define `ptn_7_3, MID(pattern,7,3),` ,`ptn_11_1, MID(pattern,11,1),` and `ptn_5_1, MID(pattern,5,1),`.  Look through your formula for ANYthing you use more than once, and define it in the outer LET.  Each duplicated calc that you define in LET reduces 37,000 calculations.

Comment: @Max thanks for the reply i will have a play with what you have suggested, hopefully this will help and will report back. if you can have a look later that would be great, 

Thanks for your help, always appreciated.